# How to export variable from beforeAll block to another module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, jasmine, jestjs

I am working on configuring in-memory database. I have to get a value from a variable which exists on beforeAll block. when i tried importing the variable the value assigned is undefined. I need to retrive the value after executing beforeAll block.

Comment: Why don't you define the variable in `testConfig.ts` instead of importing it ?

Comment: with that value i need to write some logics in beforeAll

Answer (score 2):

Move the code that does the assignment out from beforeAll and into a function in `testConfig.ts`.

## General pattern

Code that is shared between tests does not belong in a test file but rather in test helpers.